# I am unable to find the source of a UnboundLocalError for one of my variables

Tags: python

I am getting an error in my program, but I don't see the problem. The purpose of the program is display the menu and ask the user to choose a type of item and the quantity of the item. Then it will display the subtotal and the the total of it. But i know i messed up in the subtotal part, i might need help with that too if you can :D

Here is the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\COP1000\Classwork\Lab5\Lab5_6 YumYum Joint.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\COP1000\Classwork\Lab5\Lab5_6 YumYum Joint.py", line 15, in main
    total = calcTotal(subTotal, printItems)
  File "F:\COP1000\Classwork\Lab5\Lab5_6 YumYum Joint.py", line 63, in calcTotal
    return total
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment
```

Here is the code:

```
    def main():
    endProgram ="no"
    while endProgram =="no":
        print()
        print("Welcome to the burger place")

        printItems = print_items()
        yumBurger = getYum(printItems)
        greaseFries = getFries(printItems)
        sodaYum = getSoda(printItems)
        subTotal = getSub(printItems, yumBurger, greaseFries, sodaYum)
        total = calcTotal(subTotal, printItems)
        print_info(yumBurger, greaseFries, sodaYum, total, subTotal)

        endProgram = input("Do you want to end the program")

def print_items():
    print ("Enter 1 for Yum Yum Burger")
    print ("Enter 2 for Grease Yum Fries")
    print ("Enter 3 for soda Yum")
    printItems =int(input("Which burger will you like"))
    return printItems
def getYum(printItems):
    yumBurgers =0
    if (printItems ==1):
        yumBurger = int(input("How many burgers will you like: "))
    return yumBurger
def getFries(printItems):
    greaseFries =0
    if (printItems ==2):
        greaseFries =int(input("How many fries will you like: "))
    return greaseFries
def getSoda(printItems):
    sodaYum =0
    if (printItems ==3):
        sodaYum =int(input("How many sodas will you like"))
    else:
        print("Error")
    return sodaYum
def getSub(printItems, yumBurger, greaseFries, sodaYum):
    if printItems ==1:
        subTotal = (yumBurger *.99) 
    elif printItems ==2:
        subTotal = (greaseFries *.79)
    elif printItems ==3:
        subTotal = (sodaYum *1.09)
    else:
        print("Error")
    return subTotal
def calcTotal(printItems, subTotal):
    if printItems ==1:
        total = (subTotal * .06) + subTotal
    elif printItems ==2:
        total = (subTotal * .06) + subTotal
    elif printItems ==3:
        total = (subTotal * .06) + subTotal
    else:
        print("Error")
    return total
def print_info(yumBurger, greaseFries, sodaYum, total, subTotal):
    print ("You orderd",yumBurgers," burgers")
    print ("You ordered",greaseFries," fries")
    print ("You ordered",sodaYum," sodas")
    print ("The total is",total)
    print ("The subtotal is",subTotal)
main()
```

Comment: Please provide the purpose of the program and the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. And the purpose of the program is display the menu and ask the user to choose a type of item and the quantity of the item. Then it will display the subtotal and the the total of it. But i know i messed up in the subtotal part, i might need help with that too if you can :D

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions less vague. I have fixed that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you meant

```
def getFries(printItems):
    greaseFries = 0 # set default value here
    if (printItems == 2):
        greaseFries = int(input("How many fries will you like: "))

    return greaseFries
```

You have to declare / initialize the variable `greaseFries` before it is used through the body of the function. In your existing code, when `printItems` isn't `2`, the variable `greaseFries` won't be declared.

It's a good practice to declare/initalize your variable before using them.

Comment: Oh so we add the constant before the If-then statement ?

Comment: I have another error D: I updated the question above with the code and error. Please help :D

Comment: Check the `calcTotal` function. The variable `total` isn't declared.

Comment: Yes it is, i declared it above

Comment: No, what I mean is within the function. This is just the same issue you had with `getFries` function.

Comment: So do i have to move it outside the if-then or?

Comment: Yes. The same goes within `getSub`. You have to move `subTotal`.

Comment: Sorry can you show me an example of what you're talking about? Sorry i am new to coding and this is confusing.